# Why do we need to compare with the uniform distribution to select an action while the policy function did that in Deep RL

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

In the following code written by Karpathy, why do we have this line(Why do we need to compare with the uniform distribution to select an action while the policy function did that)

```
  # forward the policy network and sample an action from the returned probability
  aprob, h = policy_forward(x)
  action = 2 if np.random.uniform() < aprob else 3 # roll the dice!
```

instead of just

```
 # forward the policy network and sample an action from the returned probability
  aprob, h = policy_forward(x)
  action = 2 if 0.5 < aprob else 3 # roll the dice!
```

....Karpathy's full code from : https://gist.github.com/karpathy/a4166c7fe253700972fcbc77e4ea32c5

```
""" Trains an agent with (stochastic) Policy Gradients on Pong. Uses OpenAI Gym. """
import numpy as np
import cPickle as pickle
import gym

# hyperparameters
H = 200 # number of hidden layer neurons
batch_size = 10 # every how many episodes to do a param update?
learning_rate = 1e-4
gamma = 0.99 # discount factor for reward
decay_rate = 0.99 # decay factor for RMSProp leaky sum of grad^2
resume = False # resume from previous checkpoint?
render = False

# model initialization
D = 80 * 80 # input dimensionality: 80x80 grid
if resume:
  model = pickle.load(open('save.p', 'rb'))
else:
  model = {}
  model['W1'] = np.random.randn(H,D) / np.sqrt(D) # "Xavier" initialization
  model['W2'] = np.random.randn(H) / np.sqrt(H)
  
grad_buffer = { k : np.zeros_like(v) for k,v in model.iteritems() } # update buffers that add up gradients over a batch
rmsprop_cache = { k : np.zeros_like(v) for k,v in model.iteritems() } # rmsprop memory

def sigmoid(x): 
  return 1.0 / (1.0 + np.exp(-x)) # sigmoid "squashing" function to interval [0,1]

def prepro(I):
  """ prepro 210x160x3 uint8 frame into 6400 (80x80) 1D float vector """
  I = I[35:195] # crop
  I = I[::2,::2,0] # downsample by factor of 2
  I[I == 144] = 0 # erase background (background type 1)
  I[I == 109] = 0 # erase background (background type 2)
  I[I != 0] = 1 # everything else (paddles, ball) just set to 1
  return I.astype(np.float).ravel()

def discount_rewards(r):
  """ take 1D float array of rewards and compute discounted reward """
  discounted_r = np.zeros_like(r)
  running_add = 0
  for t in reversed(xrange(0, r.size)):
    if r[t] != 0: running_add = 0 # reset the sum, since this was a game boundary (pong specific!)
    running_add = running_add * gamma + r[t]
    discounted_r[t] = running_add
  return discounted_r

def policy_forward(x):
  h = np.dot(model['W1'], x)
  h[h<0] = 0 # ReLU nonlinearity
  logp = np.dot(model['W2'], h)
  p = sigmoid(logp)
  return p, h # return probability of taking action 2, and hidden state

def policy_backward(eph, epdlogp):
  """ backward pass. (eph is array of intermediate hidden states) """
  dW2 = np.dot(eph.T, epdlogp).ravel()
  dh = np.outer(epdlogp, model['W2'])
  dh[eph <= 0] = 0 # backpro prelu
  dW1 = np.dot(dh.T, epx)
  return {'W1':dW1, 'W2':dW2}

env = gym.make("Pong-v0")
observation = env.reset()
prev_x = None # used in computing the difference frame
xs,hs,dlogps,drs = [],[],[],[]
running_reward = None
reward_sum = 0
episode_number = 0
while True:
  if render: env.render()

  # preprocess the observation, set input to network to be difference image
  cur_x = prepro(observation)
  x = cur_x - prev_x if prev_x is not None else np.zeros(D)
  prev_x = cur_x

  # forward the policy network and sample an action from the returned probability
  aprob, h = policy_forward(x)
  action = 2 if np.random.uniform() < aprob else 3 # roll the dice!

  # record various intermediates (needed later for backprop)
  xs.append(x) # observation
  hs.append(h) # hidden state
  y = 1 if action == 2 else 0 # a "fake label"
  dlogps.append(y - aprob) # grad that encourages the action that was taken to be taken (see http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-2/#losses if confused)

  # step the environment and get new measurements
  observation, reward, done, info = env.step(action)
  reward_sum += reward

  drs.append(reward) # record reward (has to be done after we call step() to get reward for previous action)

  if done: # an episode finished
    episode_number += 1

    # stack together all inputs, hidden states, action gradients, and rewards for this episode
    epx = np.vstack(xs)
    eph = np.vstack(hs)
    epdlogp = np.vstack(dlogps)
    epr = np.vstack(drs)
    xs,hs,dlogps,drs = [],[],[],[] # reset array memory

    # compute the discounted reward backwards through time
    discounted_epr = discount_rewards(epr)
    # standardize the rewards to be unit normal (helps control the gradient estimator variance)
    discounted_epr -= np.mean(discounted_epr)
    discounted_epr /= np.std(discounted_epr)

    epdlogp *= discounted_epr # modulate the gradient with advantage (PG magic happens right here.)
    grad = policy_backward(eph, epdlogp)
    for k in model: grad_buffer[k] += grad[k] # accumulate grad over batch

    # perform rmsprop parameter update every batch_size episodes
    if episode_number % batch_size == 0:
      for k,v in model.iteritems():
        g = grad_buffer[k] # gradient
        rmsprop_cache[k] = decay_rate * rmsprop_cache[k] + (1 - decay_rate) * g**2
        model[k] += learning_rate * g / (np.sqrt(rmsprop_cache[k]) + 1e-5)
        grad_buffer[k] = np.zeros_like(v) # reset batch gradient buffer

    # boring book-keeping
    running_reward = reward_sum if running_reward is None else running_reward * 0.99 + reward_sum * 0.01
    print 'resetting env. episode reward total was %f. running mean: %f' % (reward_sum, running_reward)
    if episode_number % 100 == 0: pickle.dump(model, open('save.p', 'wb'))
    reward_sum = 0
    observation = env.reset() # reset env
    prev_x = None

  if reward != 0: # Pong has either +1 or -1 reward exactly when game ends.
    print ('ep %d: game finished, reward: %f' % (episode_number, reward)) + ('' if reward == -1 else ' !!!!!!!!')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the uniform comparison, the policy would be deterministic. For any given state, the `policy_forward` function will return the same output, so the same action will be taken every time. So there won't be any exploration of you use your proposed method. The uniform introduces some stochasticity into thr action selection, which encourages exploration. Without exploration it's essentially impossible to discover the optimal policy.

Comment: Then why cant we just use the uniform distribution to explore and train the network ?

Comment: You can, but the goal is to balance exploration and exploitation. With the code you provided, as you get more data your aprob values will be pushed closer to 0 or 1 and so the uniform will have very little influence. This way the agent naturally starts exploiting more as it understands the environment better.